# Why do boat propellers have abruptly ended hubs

Tags: fluid-dynamics

It seems intuitive to me that the hubs downstream of the boat/ship propeller (in most common pusher configuration) should gradually taper of to a point (for instance being paraboloidal). That's how most submarine propellers end.

Not the case for common pleasure and fishing boats. The hub is not only cut sharply and perpendicularly to the shaft axis but also has a cavity with bolts, shaft tip and its bolt. All those small protrusions must generate drag and on top of that the sharp lip ending the hub and surrounding the cavity must generate high speed vortices and/or turbulence.

Overall it seems far from a hydrodynamical a solution. Is there a physical reason for it?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but just guessing that a submarine doesn't want to generate any turbulence because that would make noise and make it easier to detect. Maybe you could add some illustrations to this question.

Answer (score 3):

For a typical outboard motor that an individual would run on the back of a bass boat, the motor's designers decided that noise abatement was more important than perfectly tuned hydrodynamics.  Due to this, they decided to run the motor's exhaust through the hub of the propeller and use the water to muffle the sound of the engine.  This practically requires the shape that you described.